# Convert nil to empty string using JSONDecoder and Swift

Tags: swift, swift4, jsondecoder

I am using Swift 4 and `JSONDecoder`. I have the following structure:

```
struct Customer: Codable {
    var id: Int!
    var cnum: String!
    var cname: String!
}
```

Note: the fields cannot be made optional.

Now I have a JSON string:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "cnum": "200",
        "cname": "Bob Smith"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "cnum": "201",
        "cname": null
    }
]
```

And to decode it, I use the following:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let customers = try decoder.decode([Customer].self, from: json)
```

Everything works fine except the null data gets converted to nil. My question is, what would be the easiest way to convert incoming nil to an empty string ("")?

I would like to do this with the minimum amount of code but I'm not sure about the correct approach and at what point can the nil be converted to an empty string. Thank you beforehand.

Comment: If you don't want optionals why do you declare all variables as optional?? And **NEVER** declare properties as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized with an `init` method anyway.

Comment: Vadian thank you and sorry for the confusion.  When I meant optional, I mean it cannot be: var cname: String?

Comment: If it could be `nil` declare it as *regular* optional `var cname: String?`. If not, as non-optional: `var cname: String`

Comment: Thank you Vadian, I had also tried that but that again would break objective-c calls.

Answer (score 5):

You can use backing ivars:

```
struct Customer: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var cnum: String {
        get { _cnum ?? "" }
        set { _cnum = newValue }
    }
    var cname: String {
        get { _cname ?? "" }
        set { _cname = newValue }
    }
    
    private var _cnum: String?
    private var _cname: String?
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, _cnum = "cnum", _cname = "cname"
    }
}
```

Due to the custom `CodingKeys`, the JSON decoder will actually decode to `_cnum` and `_cname`, which are optional strings. We convert nil to empty string in the property getters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use decodeIfPresent method.

```
struct Source : Codable {

    let id : String?


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"

    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id) ?? "Default value pass"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a **computed variable** that will have the original value if it's not nil and an empty string if it is.

```
var cnameNotNil: String {
    return cname ?? ""
}
```

Comment: the4kman thanks for the editing!  Thanks for the answer also but, I need the name to remain as cname though!  That would create an additional variable.  This would also break alot of other code.  Thanks.

Comment: Awesome update.  I just tried it and for some reason didSet is not running?  (placed breakpoint and code never ran inside didSet) Did you test it using JSONDecoder?

Comment: @RobertSmith I reverted my answer to the previous state because it did not work. If you want to use `cname` for the name, provide a different coding key for the original variable and rename it to something like `cnameOriginal`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to write an initializer which handles the custom behavior. The `null` value is caught in an extra `do - catch` block.

```
struct Customer: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var cnum: String
    var cname: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        cnum = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .cnum)
        do { cname = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .cname) }
        catch { cname = "" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vadian, thank you and I did try that.  But unfortunately when I put in an init, it breaks my calls to objective-c code.  The closest answer was something in the lines of "didSet" but that would not work neither.

Comment: You should have mentioned in the question how the code interacts with Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Use **decodeIfPresent** if the value from response might be null

```
cnum = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .cnum)
cname = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .cname)
```